# Recursive Delete LinkedList C++

Tags: c++, recursion, linked-list, head

Is there something I'm forgetting about when I delete a node object in C++?
I'm confused why my delete method works for in main, but doesn't work in my professor's main method when testing.

Here's some of my code for the delete method I've made.

1. It has to be recursive
2. Must de-allocate memory, and not just move the pointer.

.

```
// this is his method header
void remove (const E& x) {
   // passes in the head pointer, and the object to delete.
    _remove(head, x);
}

// Recursive remove function
void _remove(Node* &curr, const E& val){
    // if the head is null do nothing.
    // base case
    if (curr == NULL){
        return;
    }

    //case where the node found is the head.
    if (curr->data == val && curr == head){
        head = head->next;
        delete curr;
        return;
    }

    // the node may be in the middle somewhere
    if (curr->next->data == val){
        Node* del = curr->next;
        curr->next = del->next;
        delete del;
        return;
    }
    // rinse and repeat.
    _remove(curr->next, val);
}
```

Comment: What happens when `curr` points to the last element in the list? Your PC explodes.

Comment: why bother the next? You should only care about the head and tail, beside, if the current is tail, curr->next->data crushes the program. And you'd better off put all your code including main() to get understand why it works for you but not your professor.

Comment: Also, `E`? If you have an entire type defined just to contain ASCII 0x45, you're doing it wrong.

Comment: This _delete method is used for deleting a specific node in a singly linked list. It has no tail. You're correct that my computer will "explode" on that one if statement if the node is located at the end of the list.  However, a simply modification to the if statement will prevent this. The other problem I was having was that there was temporary Node pointing to the data I was supposed to delete leading to a memory leak. Finally, a linked list of type "E" is simply my template class name. Some people use T. I used E